# This.id returns undefined when inside a declared function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know variations of this have been asked hundreds of times, but after searching and reading dozens of similar questions am being particularly thick and i can't come close to working out the whys and hows of it happening, so at the risk of being shot down in flames...

Troubleshooting it i trimmed down everything to the most basic, so i got a html of the form

```
<li class='field' id='field_2'>
```

if i put down a jquery function as

```
$('.field').on('mouseenter',function(){console.log(this.id)});
```

it returns the id fine, but if i declare and call a function such as

```
function shade(){
    console.log(this.id);
};

$('.field').on('mouseenter',function(){shade()});
```

it returns 'undefined'.

Also tried within shade() passing the id as a 'var', using .attr(), etc. in  case it made a difference to no avail.

Anyone can point me on what i'm doing wrong 'for dummies' before i just give up and declare the id as a global variable within the mouseenter would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Provide a working code snippet that reproduce the issue described

Comment: `$('.field').on('mouseenter', shade);` -- pass a reference to the function instead of calling it from the anonymous function

Comment: Because this is out of function scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

```js
function shade(){
    console.log(this.id);
};

$('.field').on(
    'mouseenter', 
    function(){
        shade.call(this)
    }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class='field' id='field_2'>hover me</li>
```

Comment: Yes, that and the sugestion from datacure below both work, thanks. Just trying to get my head around the why now as i'm sure i've used the same 'structure' before without this problem. Time to put my thinking hat on i guess. Cheers.

Comment: @OLopez add `console.log(this);` in both functions. Log it with and without the `.call(this)` and note the difference. That might helps your thinking hat to clarify some things.

Answer (score 0):

I see a big problem : `this` seems to be the current item in jQuery. Here are 2 solutions :

1- You can set a `this` var :
    var this = $('.field');
    this.on('mouseenter',function(){console.log(this.id)});

2- when you want to use the current DOM cibling item in jQuery, do not user `this`, but use `$(this)` instead, with the `$`.

Comment: `var this` will lead to the following exception: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this. You can't use reserved keywords as a variable name

Comment: you can call it watever you want, it's just an exemple ^^

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery**:
The reason for this is when your using jQuery your using a function that is settings this as the event rather than the DOM Element.

See the following output:

```js
function shade(){
    console.log(this);
};

$('.field').on('mouseenter',function(){shade()});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class='field' id='field_2'>

<!-- You may have to wait a short while after you hover over the bullet point -->
```

You will need to use the traditional JavaScript as a work around.

```js
function myId(el){
 console.log (el.id);
}
```

```css
.area{ width: 50%; height: 5em; background: lime; margin: 0 auto}
```

```html
<div class="area" id="greenbox" onmouseover="myId(this)"></div>
```

Or refer to the class item as others have suggested (I will not add that to my answer as I feel others should be given credit for providing you with the solution)

Comment: Thanks, as i answered to caramba above, both your and his method work, so i have to now just do some thinking to understanding why. Thanks a lot

Comment: P.s. Seems i'm only allowed to upvote and mark as answer one of you, so as not to have to chose i left them to caramba on the basis of being the first. Sorry ;-)

Comment: Thats perfectly acceptable, thank you for taking time to share your thoughts :)